Why does OP_CHECKSIG/OP_CHECKMULTISIG remove the signature from the subscript?
When OP_CHECKSIG is used, all instances of the signature are removed from the subScript before it's included in a transaction template to be verified. See also step 3 in this excellent diagram. The same thing is done with OP_CHECKMULTISIG.
How could a copy of the signature(s) end up in the subscript? Why must it/they be removed?
